# Binary Rejected - TabletApplicationIconHD167 remains blank

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, phonegap-build

I have an phonegab build iOS App which in working fine more than 3 years.  Yesterday my iOS App Binary Rejected by Apple review team. They mentioned some icons missing in app. Here is the full details they provide.

> iPhone icon “TabletApplicationIconHD167” remains blank. For
>   information regarding app icons, you may want to refer to the iTunes
>   Connect Developer Guide

I can't get anything from google by searching "TabletApplicationIconHD167".  I tested in iPhone 6 plus and working fine.  Here I attach my icons list in my config.xml.

```
<platform name="ios">  

<!-- iPhone / iPod Touch iOS 7.0+ -->  
<icon src="res/ios/icons/icon-60.png"  width="60" height="60" />  
<icon src="res/ios/icons/icon-60@2x.png"  width="120" height="120" />  


<!-- iPad -->  
<icon src="res/ios/icons/icon-76.png"  width="76" height="76" />  
<icon src="res/ios/icons/icon-76@2x.png"  width="152" height="152" />  

<!-- Settings Icon -->  
<icon src="res/ios/icons/icon-small.png"  width="29" height="29" />  
<icon src="res/ios/icons/icon-small@2x.png"  width="58" height="58" />  

<!-- Spotlight Icon -->  
<icon src="res/ios/icons/icon-40.png"  width="40" height="40" />  
<icon src="res/ios/icons/icon-40@2x.png"  width="80" height="80" />  

<!-- iPhone / iPod Touch iOS 6.1-->  
<!-- <icon src="res/ios/icons/icon.png"  width="57" height="57" /> -->  
<icon src="res/ios/icons/icon@2x.png"  width="114" height="114" />  

<!-- iPad -->  
<icon src="res/ios/icons/icon-72.png"  width="72" height="72" />  
<icon src="res/ios/icons/icon-72@2x.png"  width="144" height="144" />  

<!-- iPhone Spotlight and Settings Icon -->  
<!-- <icon src="res/ios/icons/icon-small.png"  width="29" height="29" />  
<icon src="res/ios/icons/icon-small@2x.png"  width="58" height="58" /> -->  

<!-- iPad Spotlight and Settings Icon -->  
<icon src="res/ios/icons/icon-50.png"  width="50" height="50" />  
<icon src="res/ios/icons/icon-50@2x.png"  width="100" height="100" />  

<!-- iPhone 6 / 6+ -->  
<icon src="res/ios/icons/icon-60@3x.png"  width="180" height="180" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need an app icon for the iPad Pro which is 167x167

[App Icon Sizes](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/app-icon/)

> iPad Pro  167px × 167px (83.5pt × 83.5pt @2x)